# Getting error in wixl build after adding UIRef tag

Tags: ant, msbuild, wix, windows-installer, wixl

I am working on creating a windows installer for my application using wixl. I am getting below error when I try to run a wixl build:

> (wixl:4240): wixl-ERROR **: wix.vala:218: unhandled child Product node
>   UIRef

It was working fine until I added below instructions inside the Product tag to increase user interaction during installation:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

PS: I have integrated the wixl instructions into ant build and running it on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: wixl? hmm, never heard of that one.  Time for a new tag?

Answer (score 1):

wixl doesn't support UIRef. You can see the code at https://github.com/elmarco/wixl/blob/master/src/wix.vala#L478.

Comment: So is there a way in wixl to provide user interactions - I need to provide user the ability to specify the installation directory and prompt user after successful installation. Does wixl have these abilities?

Comment: Or a way to run wix build in Unix env?

Comment: I work on WiX, not wixl, so for details, you'd have to ask wixl people. I know some folks have tried to run WiX on Linux using Mono and Wine but I don't know how successfully.